# Why does the snake in my snake clone randomly split in half?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I have recreated the game Snake, in which the player moves a 2-dimensional snake around the screen eating apples. To do this, I have used python and turtle. However, I have encountered an issue. Sometimes, randomly, the snake splits into different pieces and you can only control one section, usually leading to death as the other piece runs into a wall. I have tried re-arranging the order of events (e.g. checking if a piece needs to turn then moving the pieces, or the other way around). I am using the `keyboard` module, so you have to run as root on Linux. I have not been able to find any answers online due to it being an unusual problem. You can find the code [on my GitHub](https://github.com/Mr-Piggy/Snake). Here is the minimal reproducible example:

```py
import turtle, time, random, keyboard
class SnakeBlock(turtle.Turtle):
    xdirections = {0:0, 1:-30, 2:0, 3: 30}
    ydirections = {0:30, 1:0, 2:-30, 3: 0}
    def __init__(self, pos, direction):
        super().__init__()
        self.penup()
        self.shape('square')
        self.shapesize(1.4285714285714286,1.4285714285714286,1)
        self.pos = pos
        self.direction = direction
        self.goto(self.pos)
    def next(self):
        self.pos = (self.pos[0]+self.xdirections[self.direction], self.pos[1]+self.ydirections[self.direction])
        self.goto(self.pos)
class Snake:
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length
        self.blocks = []
        self.turnplaces = []
        self.direction = 3
        for x in range(length):
            snake = SnakeBlock(((4-x)*30-420, 0), self.direction)
            self.blocks.append(snake)
        self.blocks.reverse()
    def left(self):
        new = {self.blocks[-1].pos: 1}
        self.turnplaces.append(new)
    def right(self):
        new = {self.blocks[-1].pos: 3}
        self.turnplaces.append(new)
    def up(self):
        new = {self.blocks[-1].pos: 0}
        self.turnplaces.append(new)
    def down(self):
        new = {self.blocks[-1].pos: 2}
        self.turnplaces.append(new)
    def checkforturns(self):
        keys = [next(iter(item.items()))[0] for item in self.turnplaces]
        values = [next(iter(item.items()))[1] for item in self.turnplaces]
        for snakeblock in self.blocks:
            if snakeblock.pos in keys:
                snakeblock.direction = values[keys.index(snakeblock.pos)]
                if self.blocks[snake.blocks.index(snakeblock)] == self.blocks[0]:
                    self.turnplaces.pop()
snake = Snake(4)
keyboard.add_hotkey('up', snake.up)
keyboard.add_hotkey('left', snake.left)
keyboard.add_hotkey('down', snake.down)
keyboard.add_hotkey('right', snake.right)
while True:
    [snakeblock.next() for snakeblock in snake.blocks]
    snake.checkforturns()
    time.sleep(0.1) 
die()
```

Answer (score 1):

In the chomp() function, where you increase the size of the snake after eating an apple, there seems to be an incorrect calculation for the position of the new block.

i.e. change

```
newpos = list(snake.blocks[0].pos)
```

to

```
newpos = list(snake.blocks[-1].pos)
```

The chomp() function should also update the pos list after adding the new block.

```
pos = [snake.pos for snake in snake.blocks]
pos.append(newblock.pos)
```

Comment: I don't see a `chomp` function anywhere in the example code in the question. Please read [answer] and keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**, and the purpose of questions here **is not** to search for a bug in OP's hundreds of lines of off-site code. For questions about the behaviour of code, the minimal necessary code to reproduce the problem **must** appear **in the question itself**, per policy.

Comment: @AndrewArrow I have just updated the question to separate my two problems, but thank you anyway. It is helpful